# How to fix "PT006 wrong name(s) type in @pytest.mark.parametrize, expected tuple"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, flake8

When I run flake8 I get the following error:

```
./test_sample.py:4:2: PT006 wrong name(s) type in @pytest.mark.parametrize, expected tuple
```

Here is my code

```
import pytest


@pytest.mark.parametrize('foo,bar', [(1, 1), (2, 2)])
def test_foo(foo, bar):
    assert foo == bar
```

`pip freeze | egrep flake8`:

```
flake8==3.8.4
flake8-plugin-utils==1.3.1
flake8-pytest-style==1.3.0
```

How do I fix the error?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This error is generated by `flake8-pytest-style`. See https://github.com/m-burst/flake8-pytest-style/blob/master/docs/rules/PT006.md

You have two options:

- Replace `'foo,bar'` with `('foo', 'bar')`

  ```py
  import pytest


  @pytest.mark.parametrize(('foo', 'bar'), [(1, 1), (2, 2)])
  def test_foo(foo, bar):
      assert foo == bar
  ```
- Change the `pytest-parametrize-names-type` configuration option by adding a file named `.flake8` with the following contents to the root of your project:

  ```
  [flake8]
  pytest-parametrize-names-type = csv
  ```